# Firebase .on("value") method is giving me a null error when I load my page. The ref does not exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase, and I have an on("value") event on a ref called Shout.  This shoutRef does not exist when you first load the page.  As soon as I land firebase says the snapshot inside the shoutRef is null.  How can I avoid this?  Why is it looking at a ref that doesn't exist?

```
    at main.js:127
    at EventRegistration.ts:133
    at qr (util.ts:586)
    at t.raise (EventQueue.ts:171)
    at t.raiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate_ (EventQueue.ts:123)
    at t.raiseEventsForChangedPath (EventQueue.ts:103)
    at t.onDataUpdate_ (Repo.ts:277)
    at h.onDataPush_ (PersistentConnection.ts:604)
    at h.onDataMessage_ (PersistentConnection.ts:597)
    at t.onDataMessage_ (Connection.ts:317)


var firebaseData = firebase.database();
    var shoutRef = firebaseData.ref("/shout ref");

 shoutRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        var snap = snapshot.val();
        //set global variable TODO:May not need in future
        console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: I don't know if anyone on Stack Overflow can tell you why data does or doesn't exist at a certain location in your database.  You should be able to tell that for yourself.

Comment: I tried pasting this code into a new project  using firebase and didn't get an error. `null` was logged instead.